# Composer can check MariaDB installation?

Tags: php, composer-php, mariadb

It is possibile to create a composer configuration that aims to check that mariadb is present/installed in the current machine?

Comment: According to this [page on getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages) no... actually on second look you may be able to use the extension checking

Answer (score 1):

i would do this by using composer scripts

> A script, in Composer's terms, can either be a PHP callback (defined as a static method) or any command-line executable command. Scripts are useful for executing a package's custom code or package-specific commands during the Composer execution process.

Source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-

Answer (score 1):

according to the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages) :

> `lib-<name>` allows constraints to be made on versions of libraries used
>   by PHP. The following are available: curl, iconv, icu, libxml,
>   openssl, pcre, uuid, xsl.

so you can check against maraiDB using :

```
"require": {
    ....
    "libmariadb2": "*",
    ....
}
```

this should throw an error like :

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package libmariadb2 could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Note: the above requirement will only check against mariaDB lib , not the php extension, to add or only check against php extension use :

```
"require": {
    ....
    "ext-pdo": "*"
    OR
    "ext-mysqli": "*"
    ....
}
```